# What would you call a form of government where the community governs itself?

Tags: meaning, government

Let us suppose that there was a society that existed on a communal level where there weren’t really any formal official laws, but rather the community sort of liquidly governed itself, using de facto social norms and social values that are strongly ingrained and maintained in the community through tradition and culture,  and instead of formal laws everything was basically fluidly governed by the community at large through what is de-facto? Basing governance on what is commonly accepted by the community and having the community enforce it by itself without an external government. This community would place a religion at its center, and the culture and values within it would be derived from that religion.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Whether you are looking for one word (See [*About single word requests*](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)), a phrase, or an idiom, you should provide (a) a detailed description to the best of your ability, (b) what terms you have tried that don't work, and (c) a **sample sentence** where you would use the term.

Comment: I think Dennis called it an *anarcho-syndicalist commune*

Comment: I have seen the word "globalization" used with the connotation you are giving.

Comment: @Jim.But..I thought it was  _autonomous collective_.

Comment: @WeatherVane: "Commune" is correct.

Comment: @Ricky 'commune' doesn't satisfy having a religion at the centre, which moves the governance from mutual consent to proscribed laws. But if OP was considering Buddhism that could qualify, as it does not have a set of rules and punishments.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Why not? There are Christian communes. There are kibbutzes. There are monasteries and convents. And, of course, cults - a less pleasant variation of the idea, but there they are.

Comment: @Ricky, they may be communes but they are not governed by consent (as the question). Cults especially, are usually under the strict control of one autocratic charismatic.

Comment: Is this a real issue that the asker is facing? I'm hard-pressed to see that. This is also a question that will solicit opinions rather than authoritative answers.

Comment: @Ricky, the OP is looking at a community that 'sort of liquidly' governs itself. While it is not entirely clear what 'sort of liquidly' amounts to, it seems to imply that the obedience to the norms is spontaneous, i.e. that there is no formal mechanism for making the decisions for the community. Communes and similar forms of social organisation typically do have some relatively formal mechanisms of decision making.

Comment: It is unlikely that there is a single word that would be immediately understood to mean precisely what is described here. If one wants to write about such a community (either in a work of fiction, or as a hypothetical in some theoretical discussion), one has to describe it, as was done in the question, and then simply stipulate 'from now on, I will refer to such a society as . . .' .

Comment: This question should probably be on [History.SE]. It's not really a matter of English language (or even English culture) but about politics or anthropology in general.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best word for this would be anarchy. Colloquially, "anarchy" is associated with chaos and disorder, but linguistically and in the context of many political theories (e.g. anarcho-communism) anarchy simply means the absence of government.

Two definitions given by [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anarchy):

a) absence of government

c) a utopian society of individuals who enjoy complete freedom without government

While this term doesn't capture your point about values and actions being based on a shared religion, it also doesn't preclude the centering of religion in this community and is the best way to define the "form of government" or lack thereof.

If you want a single word to describe not only the way the community is governed, but the community way of life more broadly, I would probably say the best word would be "Christian*-anarchist-communism". Someone in the comments of the main post suggested syndicalism, but I don't think this is quite right as it implies control of the economy by workers.

*or whatever adjective applies to the religion of the commune

Your description of this community sounds much more like anarchist communism as described by Kropotkin in "The Conquest of Bread" wherein it is not just the workers who have seized the means of production who thus enjoy the fruits of their labor, but rather that the fruits of all labor are shared and applied towards the well-being of all members of the community.

> "All is for all! If the man and the woman bear their fair share of work, they have a right to their fair share of all that is produced by all, and that share is enough to secure them well-being. No more of such vague formulas as "The right to work," or "To each the whole result of his labour." What we proclaim is The Right to Well-Being: Well-Being for All!

Answer (score 0):

That would be the idea  expressed by the concept of perfect democracy.

***[Perfect democracy](https://medium.com/the-hard-problem-of-everything/a-perfect-democracy-fded99ff1472)***

> Democracy is, by definition, the rule of the people, that is ALL of the people, rather than some or even most of them. Therefore, in a perfect world, any truly democratic political decision would be a product of a total consensus between all the people (or at least their representatives), but alas, that’s hardly realistic.

[Referendums](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/referendum) are examples  of “perfect democracy”.

Comment: Except that in a referendum, the opinion of 49% of the population might be totally ignored. Perhaps if a compromise were possible ....